# How to Save set image of PickedFile type to a image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to set get image from the camera and set it to the following code:

```
image: DecorationImage(image: FileImage(file),
```

So I did this:

```
File file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
  source: ImageSource.camera,
);
```

Now above code works fine for now, but 'pickImage' is deprecated and we should use imagePicker.getImage() method instead.

So I used imagePicker.getImage() instead:

```
PickedFile file = await ImagePicker().getImage(
  source: ImageSource.camera,
);
```

But when I try to set this file to the following image type, it doesn't work

```
image: DecorationImage(image: FileImage(file),)
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: `final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(...);
final File file = File(pickedFile.path);`

and then... 
`image: DecorationImage(image: FileImage(file),)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use path property of picked file

```
image: DecorationImage(image: FileImage(File(file.path)),)
```

Answer (score 13):

If someone might struck on a similar issue

change from pickImage to getImage and still needs a File.

```
PickedFile selectedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: source);
File selected = File(selectedFile.path);
```

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck in a similar type of problem where

`await ImagePicker.pickImage( source: ImageSource.camera, );`

was deprecated, and I have to use

`await ImagePicker().getImage( source: ImageSource.camera, );`

but the problem raised when I wanted to save it,
so if anyone stuck in suck kind of the problem I used this hack

`final savedImage = File(imageFile.path).copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');`

this is one part of my code...

Answer (score 0):

PickedFile to File
If your app needs dart:io File objects to operate, you may transform PickedFile to File like so:

```dart
final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(...);

final File file = File(pickedFile.path);
```