# PickedFile - How to show image on web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

The user picks an image (resulting in PickedFile - a class that is supported on web), and I want to present that image on the screen (another screen).

For Android and iOS it's very simple:

```
Image.file(
            File(widget.pickedFile.path),
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          )
```

(see also [How to Save set image of PickedFile type to a image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62128847/how-to-save-set-image-of-pickedfile-type-to-a-image-in-flutter)).

However, for Web, the class File isn't supported.
How do I present the user with an Image on Web?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show picked image with file\_picker in web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303901/how-to-show-picked-image-with-file-picker-in-web)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying it personally, I suspect that PickedFile is a list of bytes.

Image has another constructor Image.memory() so my first suggestion is:

```
Uint8List pickedFileBytes = await widget.pickedFile.readAsBytes(); 
Image.memory(pickedFileBytes, fit: BoxFit.scaleDown);
```

Comment: The argument type 'PickedFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.

Comment: I believe the conversion is readAsBytes so try

Comment: so try the new version above.

Answer (score 4):

To display pickedFile (local storage images) on Flutter Web use:

```
Image.network(file.path)
```

Hope this works for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

file_picker: file.path not work in web becuase path always null.
solution: use file.bytes instead.
so try this solution worked for me :

```
Image.memory(
 controller.file!.bytes!,
 fit: BoxFit.fill,
 height: 270,
 width: Get.width,
)
```